# dart: what is the meaning of class constructor being marked as const

Tags: dart

So I have seen code as such:

```dart
class Whatever {
  final String name;
  const Whatever(this.name);
}
```

What does change by the fact that the constructor is marked with `const`? Does it have any effect at all?

I have read this:

> Use const for variables that you want to be compile-time constants. If
>   the const variable is at the class level, mark it static const.
>   (Instance variables can’t be const.)

but it does not seem to make sense for the class constructor.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- The constructor can't have a constructor body.
- All members have to be final and must be initialized at declaration or by the constructor arguments or initializer list.
- You can use an instance of this class where only constants are allowed (annotation, default values for optional arguments, ...)
- You can create constant fields like `static const someName = const Whatever()`;

If the class doesn't have a const constructor it can't be used to initialize constant fields. I think it makes sense to specify this at the constructor. You can still create instances at runtime with `new Whatever()` or add a factory constructor.

See also

- [Dartlang const constructor - how is it different to "regular" constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744677)
- [Dart factory constructor - how is it different to “const” constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756593)
- [How to make a factory constructor that returns as const value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380792)
- [Why does Dart have compile time constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418819)
- [How to write abstract class constructors so that it will be flexible for extending in sub classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698982)

The "old style" (still valid) enum is a good example how to use const
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15854550/217408